# Adjusting button width in UITableViewController (Swift - Xcode)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

i would like to know how can i adjust my UIButton to be stationary at the bottom so lets say even if there are a lot of tableview cells. The button will still stay put in the bottom.

[image]

Comment: have you added the constraint in the storyboard to the button?

Comment: ermm no, how do u do that?

Comment: Add `button.width` Constraint with fix value as you want, from Your `Storyboard` or `xib` in `Interface builder`

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/understanding-auto-layout-in-xcode-9-2719710f0706 : try this blog

Comment: set a view in TableViewController3 and set a button in that view than set constraint properly

Comment: actually guys forget what i just said, i want the button to stay stationary at the bottom even if there are a lot of tableview cells. like https://ibb.co/e5SCd7

Comment: You can have another element above table view inside Table View Controller.  Try @Rocky's solution

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are 3 ways to achieve that in my knowledge.

**1 -> By Using `UIViewController` instead of `UITableViewController`**

In `UIViewController` you can add `UITableView` , then add `UIButton` at the bottom of the `UIViewController` as per your requirement.

**2 -> Add Button on the `UINavigationController View`**

You can add a button on `UINavigationController's view` (if you are using `UINavigationController`) programmatically.

**3 -> Add Button on the `Application Window`**

You can add a button on `UIWindow` programmatically.

***For 2nd & 3rd point***

These cases are applicable when you want to use only `UITableViewController`. For this you need to create a button programmatically in your `TableViewController`.

```
 let button : UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setTitle("Redeem", for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .green
    return button
}()
```

Then add the button either on `UIWindow` or on `UINavigationController's view` , like this:

If you want to add button `UIWindow`

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
    {
        window.addSubview(button)

        button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: window.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
      let bottomSpaceConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[v0(40)]-20-|", options: .init(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["v0" : button])
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(bottomSpaceConstraints)
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    }
}
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    button.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

and if you want to add it in `UINavigationController`.

```
   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if let navigationView = self.navigationController?.view
    {
        navigationView.addSubview(button)
        button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
      let bottomSpaceConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[v0(40)]-20-|", options: .init(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["v0" : button])
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(bottomSpaceConstraints)
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    }
}
```

***Remember*** 
In both cases 2nd & 3rd, You should remove that button in `viewWillDisappear` method, cause you don't want that button appear on every screen.

In All cases result would be something like this:

[image]

Comment: actually so sorry bro, forget about my qn, i actually want the button to stay stationary at the bottom even if there are a lot of tableview cells. like https://ibb.co/e5SCd7

Comment: Alright thanks so much for the help Arun. I’ll try that tmr and get back to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to get a FIXED button on bottom on as you required follow the below steps:

1. Add a `UIViewController` on your `Storyboard`
2. Add a `UITableView` on `UIViewController`
3. Add a `UIView` at bottom of `UIViewController` with Fixed Height
4. Add Constraints to `UIView` for bottom, left, right to its super view & Make `UIView.height` `Constraints` a fix value
5. Add `Constraints` to `UITableView` for top, left, right to its superview & bottom with `UIView`
6. Add a `UIButton` on `UIView` with Horizontally & Vertically centre to its superview

for your reference [demo project zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yd3qqky0rartr1r/FixSticky.zip?dl=0) also added with these steps

Comment: Alright thanks so much for the help Rocky. I’ll try that tmr and get back to you :)